# ackermann_msgs for Eloquent

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to check if ackermann_msgs package is supported for eloquent.
But in this link I find that its faded out for eloquent.
https://index.ros.org/p/ackermann_msgs/#dashing
According to my understanding, the dashing version should be able to work with eloquent. Is this wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355543/ackermann_msgs-for-eloquent/) by [Priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/55994/priya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sure that if you asked the maintainers, they'd run bloom for Eloquent and now Foxy. You are correct that if they provide Dashing messages, they will most probably work in ROS2 Eloquent / Foxy without an issue by building from source.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0